# How to change div border color when click the div in Vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js

How can I change the border color when click the **div** here is the minimal example >>> [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-border-color-when-clicked-idg2e4?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:526-609)

HTML

```
 <div class="t1" v-for="text in myArray" :key="text" @click="Clicktochgcolor()">
      {{text}}
 </div>
```

Script

```
 data(){
    return{
      myArray:[
        'Test','Test2','Test3'
      ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    Clicktochgcolor(){
      // Change color here
    }
  }
```

CSS

```
.t1{
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding:6px;
  margin:6px;
  border-radius:8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
 <div class="t1" :class="{active: activeList[index]}" v-for="(text, index) in myArray" :key="text" @click="Clicktochgcolor(index)">
      {{text}}
 </div>
```

Script

```
  data(){
    return{
      myArray:[
        'Test','Test2','Test3'
      ],
      activeList: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.activeList = new Array(this.myArray.length).fill(false)
  },
  methods:{
    Clicktochgcolor(index){
      // Change color here
      this.activeList = this.activeList.map(() => false)
      this.activeList[index] = true

    }
  }
```

CSS

```
.t1{
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding:6px;
  margin:6px;
  border-radius:8px;
}
.t1.active{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```